# Vim YouCompleteMe Pattern Not Found Error

Tags: javascript, vim, plugins, homebrew, macvim

I'm getting the following error in MacVim on Yosemite from YouCompleteMe whenever I write Javascript. It happens almost every line.

[image: Error Message]

Can someone please help me silence this message?

I know I am running the latest version of MacVim w/ homebrew. I have tried this [patch](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4770) but it didn't work.

Comment: Sadly, I don't think there is any way of silencing this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade to include vim patch 7.4.314 and the message will automatically disappear if you are using YouCompleteMe.

Patch 7.4.314 introduced the shortmess c option which disables that message. From `:help shortmess`

```
 c don't give |ins-completion-menu| messages.  For example,
    "-- XXX completion (YYY)", "match 1 of 2", "The only match",
    "Pattern not found", "Back at original", etc.
```

YCM will automatically set this if it detects that vim has the necessary patch.

macports does not currently support up to this patch level. So the only options is to either wait until macports adds it or compile from source.

Comment: I see...well thank you for the help! Also thanks for the edit! I suppose I'll wait until macports upgrades to that patch. I don't want to mess with compiling from source right now.

Comment: Hello there, May I ask How can I upgrade Vim? I have tried: *brew upgrade vim* and it runs and downloads the latest version (7.4.889), but when I open vim it still says it's version: (7.4.258), What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Jose you might want to upgrade macvim if you installed that one originally. Other than that I don't know.

Comment: Thank you, sir. I had to delete vim completely from my system, and then install again in order for it update. :(